# Blocking app from Android by router?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, android

I am wondering if its possible to block an app by the router? By blocking the website of the app?

I blocked the Android from connected to router with the Wifi, but some-how they got it to work again. I know they was searching for static IP and how to get one. So I'm assuming they learned how to switch to the static IP and that is how theyre device works again.

I really just want to block one app from them. For example, let's say it's skout.com android app that they are using.

Is it possible to block skout.com by there router and that will stop the skout.com APP from connecting to the internet?

Comment: This probably depends on *exactly what router you're talking about*.

Comment: Who are "they" and "them"?  If these are people over which you have some authority (say, children, subordinate co-workers, students, etc.), then maybe it'd be worthwhile to look at non-technical measures, especially if they have a higher level of technical savvy than you do.  Besides, many Android devices are cell phones, and can simply access data via the cellular network instead of your WiFi, or they can use a nearby Access Point if any are available (which is common in many urban/suburban settings).

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the setup of your router's firewall, you should be able to block specific sites and/or IP addresses.  You will need to consult the help manual/files for your model of router to see what features it will support.  If you want to block their Android entirely, you might consider implementing MAC filtering on your router, it it's WIFI configuration will support it and block their phone entirely.

Comment: I thought I did block the android device from Router from Verizon's parental controls. But if changing the  ip to Static be able to by pass it? (What would the static IP be able to by pass?)

Comment: +1 for MAC filtering. Also, what sort of encryption do you have set up on the WiFi? You really don't want untrusted devices running ANY apps on your network if you can help it.

Comment: It's WEP. Also, so blocking skout.com should also block there access to the skout's app?

Comment: If that is indeed the address it is connecting to, that would block the app from utilizing your network.  On the blocking, it's possible that you only blocked the device's IP address at the time.  I am not familiar with the Verizon controls.  If it was blocked by IP address, then changing the address would "unblock" it.

Comment: As a side note, WEP is a very unsecure encryption for wifi.  You should consider updating the encryption to WPA2 if it is supported on your wireless network.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is the APP in question is down-loadable from multiple sources, not just the SKOUT site. So blocking the web site won't do the trick. Not knowing how the APP connects specifically it can not be easily blocked by the firewall.

I know you didn't ask but I am going to say this anyway; IMO, you should change the security settings and password on the router. When the person wants to use the network, they will have to ask. If they download the APP again, they lose access. If this is your device, take it away from the person borrowing it.